# Upgrading 2.1.16 to 2.3.2 Magento and PHP version issues

Tags: magento2, upgrade, centos

**We are attempting to upgrade from version 2.1.16 to 2.3.2 on CentOS7.**

*Previously we were running PHP 5.6.30. I uninstalled that version, installed version 7.2.20, and received the following errors when attempting the upgrade.*

*What is strange to me that using the upgrade utility in the admin pages is able to move past this check, however running it through the command line encounters these issues.*

> My question then is, am I missing a step here, or do I need to run
>   multiple successive upgrades (eg. upgrade to PHP 7.0.0 -> upgrade to
>   Magento 2.2 -> upgrade to PHP 7.1 -> upgrade Magento 2.3 -> upgrade to
>   PHP 7.2)?

```
- magento/framework 100.1.18 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.17 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.16 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.15 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.14 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.13 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.12 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.11 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.10 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.9 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.2.0-rc20 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.8 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.7 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.6 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.5 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.4 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.3 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.2 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.1 requires php ~5.6.0|7.0.2|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.0 requires php ~5.6.0|7.0.2|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.0-rc3 requires php ~5.6.0|7.0.2|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.0-rc2 requires php ~5.5.22|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.0-rc1 requires php ~5.5.22|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.18 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.17 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.16 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.15 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.14 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.13 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.12 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.11 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.10 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.9 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.2.0-rc20 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.8 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.7 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.6 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.5 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.4 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.3 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.2 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.1 requires php ~5.6.0|7.0.2|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.0 requires php ~5.6.0|7.0.2|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.0-rc3 requires php ~5.6.0|7.0.2|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.0-rc2 requires php ~5.5.22|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/framework 100.1.0-rc1 requires php ~5.5.22|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

Comment: described what you did in order to upgrade. upgrade to 2.3.X is not that simple

Comment: @PhilippSander Followed the documentation as much as possible. Downloaded the new version, replaced my update folder with new one, updated the composer.json, uninstalled all PHP extensions, installed new ones, ran composer update.

Comment: "much as possible" what did you skip?

Comment: @PhilippSander 
php composer.phar install --no-dev
 -> 
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
 -> 
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
 -> 
composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition=2.3.2 --no-update
 -> 
composer create-project --repository=https://repo.magento.com magento/project-enterprise-edition=2.3.2 temp_dir --no-install
 -> 
rm -rf update
 -> 
mv temp_dir/update .
 -> 
rm -rf temp_dir
 -> 
composer update

Comment: but that's not all you have to do.... did you run the "pre_composer_update_2.3.php" ?

Comment: Tried that as well. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

I finally discovered the issue. In the composer.json we had "magento/data-migration-tool": "2.1.3" leftover from the Magento 1 to 2 upgrade. Removing that fixed the issue.

Comment: Have you got any DB error while upgrade from 2.1.16 to 2.3.2 directly? I am also trying to upgrade magento and getting customer group id error

Comment: @Yogendra-eCommerceDeveloper had something similar. Resolution was just to add in the missing column.